# spring integration to register dynamic ServerWebSocketContainer paths so different integration flows can be created with different paths

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-websocket

```
@Component
public class WebSocketRegistration {

  @Autowired
  GenericWebApplicationContext context;
  @Autowired
  private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

  public String registerServerEndpoint(String beanName, String endPoint) {
    context.registerBean(beanName, ServerWebSocketContainer.class,
        () -> new ServerWebSocketContainer(endPoint).withSockJs(),
        beanDefinition -> beanDefinition.setAutowireCandidate(true));
    return beanName;
  }

  public StandardIntegrationFlow webSocketFlow(String beanName) {
    ServerWebSocketContainer serverWebSocketContainer = (ServerWebSocketContainer) context
        .getBean(beanName);
    WebSocketOutboundMessageHandler webSocketOutboundMessageHandler = new WebSocketOutboundMessageHandler(
        serverWebSocketContainer);
    StandardIntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from("stringChannel")
        .split(new AbstractMessageSplitter() {
          @Override
          protected Object splitMessage(Message<?> message) {

            return serverWebSocketContainer
                .getSessions()
                .keySet()
                .stream()
                .map(s -> {
                  System.out.println(message.getPayload().toString() + " and key " + s);
                  return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message)
                      .setHeader(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.SESSION_ID_HEADER, s)
                      .build();
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
          }
        })
        .handle(webSocketOutboundMessageHandler).get();

    String id = flowContext.registration(flow).register().getId();
    System.out.println(id);
    return flow;
  }
}
```

This is sample code to register integration flow so that websocket can publish data to specified endpoint at runtime. i am not sure if spring websocket allows it but it does not throw any errors while i register a flow at runtime with different websocket urls.

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic `ServerWebSocketContainer` bean registration is not possible at the moment.
It is fully tied with the application context initialization phase.

Even if you don't get any errors registering that bean via `context.registerBean()`, the `HandlerMapping` is not updated for new path and its mapping.

I would suggest to take a look into a generic `ServerWebSocketContainer` and some "selector" logic when you try to chose sessions from the container to decide to whom to send a message to.

Feel free to raise a GH issue to improve this WebSocket support in Spring Integration.
In fact we have now dynamic HTTP & WebFlux registration.

Comment: See related issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3533